# How to add icon MUI Datatable?

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I'm using MUI DataTable and I'm trying to add "Add Icon" to the toolbar. I've tried this: https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/examples/customize-toolbar/CustomToolbar.js but it didnt work.
Error:
**Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.**
What's the proper and simplest way to add this icon? I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the package `@material-ui/icons`?

Answer (score -1):

As I see in the provided link your class component is exported as default.
Thus, please make sure that, in the component that the MUI Datatable is located, you are importing the custom toolbar component like this:

```
import CustomToolbar from '...path/to/CustomToolbar';
```

and not like this:

```
import {CustomToolbar} from '...path/to/CustomToolbar';
```

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question. This is about adding the `AddIcon` to the toolbar, not necessarily how to import the `CustomToolbar`.

Comment: @RossSheppard if he implemented the mui-datatable example fully (in the link) i believe that the error message is directing us towards an issue on how the component is imported. In the example it is shown that the component is indeed exported and is of default type; so import is the only thing remaining for checking.

Comment: I'm just wondering if it has something to do with the import of the `AddIcon`, not necessarily the `CustomToolbar`.

Comment: @RossSheppard Got your point; yes the very first thing to look into would be the imports in the CustomToolbar component file itself